# Trying to format a date with toISOString format that offsets the timezone in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, datetime, format

I have a group of Radio buttons that when clicked, set state of dates that a user may want to apply filters to for a dashboard.

The issue I was having was that when converting this date to ISOString format on click, it wasn't taking into account time different, for example here where current year is selected:

[image]

It gives me 22:00 as the time although it should be midnight. I was able to solve this thanks to an answer I found on here which offsets the timezone with IsoString (toISOStringWithTimezone function)

But now I'm not sure what kind of date format this is and how to return the formatted date with a function I created.

This is my code along with the formatdate function I am trying to create, and the IsoString function I found for offsetting the timezone.

The response I keep getting back is 'invalid time value'.

```
const onSwitchValueChange = useCallback((val) => {

          const toISOStringWithTimezone = date => {
            const tzOffset = -date.getTimezoneOffset();
            const diff = tzOffset >= 0 ? '+' : '-';
            const pad = n => `${Math.floor(Math.abs(n))}`.padStart(2, '0');
            return date.getFullYear() +
              '-' + pad(date.getMonth() + 1) +
              '-' + pad(date.getDate()) +
              'T' + pad(date.getHours()) +
              ':' + pad(date.getMinutes()) +
              ':' + pad(date.getSeconds()) +
              diff + pad(tzOffset / 60) +
              ':' + pad(tzOffset % 60);
          };

        switch (val) {
            case SwitchOptions.this_month:
                const this_month = new Date();

                const start = toISOStringWithTimezone(startOfMonth(this_month));
                const end = toISOStringWithTimezone(endOfMonth(this_month));
                
                setBaseDates({from: start, to: end});
                break;
            case SwitchOptions.custom:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        setSwitchValue(val)

    }, [setSwitchValue, SwitchOptions, setBaseDates])
```

This should then return the formatted date on the Modal like so:

[image]

Using this return code:

```
return <Modal className={"dates-filter-modal"} close={close}>
        <ModalBody>
            <Heading align={"center"} level={"2"}>{t("pages.transactions.filters.modals.dates.title")}</Heading>
            <Radio options={switchOptions}
                   value={switchValue}
                   onChange={onSwitchValueChange} />
            <ChipList setList={() => setBaseDates({from: "", to: ""})}
                      list={(!!baseDates.from && !!baseDates.to) ? [{label: "dates", value: baseDates}] : []}
                      render={() => <><CryptoIcon name={"calendar"} />{t(`pages.transactions.filters.date`).replace("[from]", t(formatRelativeDate(baseDates.from))).replace("[to]", t(formatRelativeDate(baseDates.to)))}</>}
                      removable={true}/>
        </ModalBody>
    </Modal>
```

Here I use formatRelativeDate to format and return the date in the UI, which is this function below, but it is tailored to the format I was getting before offsetting the timezone:

```
export const formatRelativeDate = (rawDate, dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX") => {
    const date = parseDate(rawDate, dateFormat)
    if (isToday(date)) return "common.dates.today";
    if (isYesterday(date)) return "common.dates.yesterday";
    if (isThisYear(date)) return formatDate(date, "dd MMM");
    return formatDate(date, "dd MMM yyyy");
}
```

This is now what I get back in the console thanks to the toISOStringWithTimezone:

[image]

What do I need to change the 'dateFormat' to in order to account for the +03:00 instead of before when it was 000Z?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: ... `+03:00` -> `.000Z`?

Answer (score 0):

here is working code for based provided time zone with use of dayjs.

```js
function makeTimeZone(date, timeZone) {
  // example of time zone +05:00
  const timeZoneChange = timeZone.slice(1, timeZone.length).split(':');
  const add = timeZone.startsWith('+') ? true : false;
  return addSubTractDependOnTimeZone(date, timeZoneChange, add);
}

function addSubTractDependOnTimeZone(dateTime, timeZone, add, format = 'YYYY-M-DD HH:mm:ss') {
  if (add) {
    return dayjs(dateTime)
        .add(+timeZone[0], 'h')
        .add(+timeZone[1], 'm')
        .format(format);
  } else {
    return dayjs(dateTime)
        .subtract(+timeZone[0], 'h')
        .subtract(+timeZone[1], 'm')
        .format(format);
  }
}

console.log(makeTimeZone('2021-12-31T22:00:00.000Z', '+05:00'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs@1.8.21/dayjs.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Code–only answers aren't particularly helpful. A good answer explains why the OP has their issue and how to fix it.